# Есть 1с 8.2. Нужно сформировать с помощью фонового задания печатную форму договора и сохранить на сервере

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Изначально проблему решали с помощью Word. Не понравилось, так как для того, чтобы все работало как часы (не знаю, возможно ли такое вообще) нужно раздать кучу прав на сервере, да и не забыть через какое-то время при переустановке или изменениях. 
Следующий вариант, запуск внешнего приложения для формирования pdf. Но тоже оказалось не все гладко.
Думаю, что кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным заданием и придумали что-то интересное. Поделитесь идеей.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Сформировать таб.док и сохранить его, хоть в эксель, хоть в pdf. Решается средствами платформы без дополнительного ПО.

Answer (score 0):

Штатными средствами платформы формируете стандартные печатные формы 1С и сохраняете на диск как pdf опять же штатными средствами. неприятность только одна - надо будет перевести ваш Word шаблон на макеты 1С. и "кто попало" не сможет создавать разнообразные шаблоны под каждый чих, что можно рассматривать как плюс - будет меньше колхоза.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем пользователя с правами Администратора (в 1С)
На сервере запускаем с ярлыка или прописываем в Шедулере:
Запускаем 1С с ключами командной строки, где указываем: базу к которой подключаемся, юзера1с (которого создали), и его пароль, и обработку которая запустится сразу после старта.
Обработка формирует печатную форму и сохраняет на диск. По опыту лучше использовать Эксель. Копируем шаблон эксель-файла, открываем обработкой, заполняем, закрываем.